# calculating time elasped on a particular location using Geolocation in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, maps, location, android-location

Android provides geolocation api for handling user location using gps,gsm or wifi.
With this, one can determine the current location of user.
My method is solely based on the inputs from the gps-receiver

Using Geolocation API, how can i determine for how long a user is on a particular geolocation ?

Answer (score 1):

Try with a runnable like:

```
  private Handler handler = new Handler();

  public static final int timeElapsedCheckingDelay = 100; // in ms

  private float timeElapsed = 0;

  private Runnable timeElapsedChecker = new Runnable()
  {
      public void run()
      {
          if(gpsActual != gpsLast) //get the last position and check
          {
            //You can export wherever for example a toast
            timeElapsed = 0; 
            gpsActual = gpsLast;
          }
          else
            timeElapsed +=0.1;

          handler.removeCallbacks(timeElapsedChecker); // remove the old callback
          handler.postDelayed(timeElapsedChecker, timeElapsedCheckingDelay); 


      }
  };
```

This is more or less pseudocode hope that it helps you :)

Comment: This would more likely solve the issue.
but, as per my experience this wont tolerate the accuracy issues.
The gps may point to a location which is close by, but user has not moved from his place.
under such circumstance it wont give the correct result.

Comment: In that case when you check your position you have to know the error of gps, and calculate your position in a interval of values. For example 2 meters of radio, else I think there cant have a solution, because the coordinates are not exact.

Comment: yes, i get it. i will need to set a distance threshold where in a change within say 50 metres  will be discarded.